# Convert string to tuple on Python

Tags: python

Hello I have a tuple in string that I revive from a PostgreSQL function>  I want to convert that to a tuple but it gives me an error with the real string inside the tuple an EOF error, the code it's like this.

```
eval('(4125, <html>
<body>
Heloo There!
<body>
</html>)')
```

, this is just an example of the HTML because the real code it's to big. I don't want to do a for because are many character so could put me very slow the system.

I am open to all the ideas except the for or while.

Comment: Could you give a clearer example of exactly what you want to convert *from* and what you want to convert *to*?

Comment: What's wrong with `for` or `while`?

Comment: Karmastan, i had a big tuple in string i was looking for convert that in a real Tuple.

Comment: Mark, the for or the while could make me slow the system if i had to extract large strings.

Comment: Robus, i will use split so i will finally use List.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the 'real' string isn't a string.

```
'(4125, <html>
<body>
Heloo There!
<body>
</html>)'
```

now remove the single quotes to get

```
(4125, <html>
<body>
Heloo There!
<body>
</html>)
```

now remove the parenthesis and the first element

```
<html>
<body>
Heloo There!
<body>
</html>
```

See, no string.

And shame on you for using `eval` on a string from a database. Didn't your parents raise you better?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and you're right, that was a bad use of eval.

Comment: But man all what is inside it's a string, is '4157, "Hello", "End"' i can't use anything to convert that into a tuple.

Comment: data =value.strip("'")
print(tuple(data[1:-1])) This was my last idea.

Comment: @hidura, try `data = tuple(str(v) for v in value.split(','))` where `value = '4157, "Hello", "End"'`. This assumes that you want a tuple of strings. If that isn't correct, you'll have to post another question. They're free ;)

Comment: I did this 
>>> data='(1, 2, "hello\n")'
>>> newData = data.strip("()")
>>> newData
'1, 2, "hello\n"'
>>> newTpl = newData.split(', ')
>>> newTpl
['1', '2', '"hello\n"']
, strip gave me a list, that list i used to create the new tuple, thank you for the advice. The data it was already a string.